# Shell script to recursively copy files with unique filenames to new folders

Tags: bash, macos, shell, glob, cp

I'm trying to restructure my files into new directories based on the filesnames. This is being done via `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)` on `OS X High Sierra`

Currently I have a parent directory, with 2 sets of subdirectories, with 100+ subdirectories, and then a set of images with filesnames that are common amongst the 3000 or so files I have throughout.

So Parent(dir) -> Subcategories(dirs) -> Deeper subcategories(dirs) -> Files

The filenames are all very similar, ie login.png or splash.png and I probably only have 40 unique filenames across 3000 files. The subcategories however are unique.

I am trying to copy all of the identical filenames recursively (ie all of the login.png files) into a new folder, but rename them all with an arbitrary unique identifier. This unique identifier does not matter whatsoever. It could be an arbitrary number or even the parent directory name (ie `login_subdirectoryname.png`)

I've tried several things just to even get a list of all available files:

So using something like this at least shows me all of the files available:

```
find ./Parent -name "*.PNG" -type f -exec echo_name.sh basename {} \;
```

Where `echo_name.sh` is just simply:

```
echo_name(){
    echo $1
}
echo_name $1
```

I created a function because I assume we'll need to do more behavior, such as check for a folder that exists with the name "login" in the new directory, and if its not available, create it.

So I need to be able to accomplish two things here...

A) Maintain some unique variable to count within the `find` function that gets passed to the `echo_name.sh` so each filename simply increments by one (ie. `login_1.png`), ***or*** appending the parent directory name (ie. `login_thissubcategory. png`) to avoid duplicate filenames when I create the actual `cp`

B) Identify what the strict filename is without the extension and the path as well as identify the path. So my function needs to know:

- ./Parent/subcategory/deeper_subcategory/login.PNG
- deeper_subcategory
- login

I know its a complicated restructure but any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a specific question, and "any help" is rather vague. Is something not working as you expect it to?

Comment: `$1` will just be the word `basename`, not the filename. You're not actually executing the `basename` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` and `xargs` combined with an inline `bash` script to effect this:

```
$ mkdir -p parent/category{1,2}/subcat{a,b,c,d,e}/
$ touch parent/category{1,2}/subcat{a,b,c,d,e}/{login,splash}.png
$ find . -type f | nl | xargs -n2 -I@ bash -c 'set -- @; b=${2##*/}; echo cp $2 ${b%.*}_$1.${b##*.}'
cp ./parent/category1/subcata/login.png login_1.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcata/splash.png splash_2.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcatb/login.png login_3.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcatb/splash.png splash_4.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcatc/login.png login_5.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcatc/splash.png splash_6.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcatd/login.png login_7.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcatd/splash.png splash_8.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcate/login.png login_9.png
cp ./parent/category1/subcate/splash.png splash_10.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcata/login.png login_11.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcata/splash.png splash_12.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcatb/login.png login_13.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcatb/splash.png splash_14.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcatc/login.png login_15.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcatc/splash.png splash_16.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcatd/login.png login_17.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcatd/splash.png splash_18.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcate/login.png login_19.png
cp ./parent/category2/subcate/splash.png splash_20.png
```

The first two lines just set up the test harness. The last line is the interesting one. Let's break it down:

```
find . -type f | \ # use find to locate the files -- change this as needed
    nl | \ # number each line -- this gives us the unique id for each
    xargs -n2 -I@ \ # pass the line number and full file name to each...
        bash -c \ # ... instance of bash we start
            'set -- @; b=${2##*/}; echo cp $2 ${b%.*}_$1.${b##*.}'
```

The meat inside the quotation marks is as follows:

- `set -- @` split the two arguments into `$1` (line #) and `$2` (full path to file)
- `b=${2##*/}` gets the base name of the file
- `echo cp $2` echoes the start of the cp command - remove `echo` to do it, tweak as necessary
- `${b%.*}_$1.${b##*.}` gets the part of the filename without extension, adds an _ to the end, adds the line number, then adds back the . extension part.

I eschew handling file names with spaces, nulls, new lines, and other non-ASCII characters as the OP suggested this wasn't issue. If this *is* an issue, additional techniques will be required.